# unaligned access store on intel processor

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the sample below. It segfaults with gcc 5.4 at the marked line when 
I compile it with `g++ -O3 -std=c++11`. It fails at instruction `movaps` and I suspect it performs unaligned memory access. Could it be that gcc generates illegal code for such a simple sample or I am missing something?
I am running it on Intel i5-5200U.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

__attribute__ ((noinline))
void SerializeTo(const vector<uint64_t>& v, uint8_t* dest) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(dest) = v[i];  // Segfaults here.
    dest += sizeof(uint64_t);
  }
}

int main() {
 std::vector<uint64_t> d(64);

 unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> tmp(new uint8_t[1024]);

 SerializeTo(d, tmp.get() + 6);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could look at the generated code with `g++ -S -O2 -fverbose-asm`

Comment: With -O2 it does not generate vectorized code.

Comment: Then replace `-O2` by whatever optimization you want, e.g. `-O3 -march=native`

Comment: then it segfaults. I do not follow

Comment: Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), notably [Lattner's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). And trust more the compiler: it is much more tested than your code is. Please blame your code, not the compiler, at first. So indeed, you are missing something. Try also other compilers (e.g. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...) and versions. Enable all warnings (with `-Wall -Wextra`)

Comment: Thank you very much @BasileStarynkevitch. I also trust more compiler. That's why I ask here for advices. Yours is not very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few ways to perform type punning legally in c++.

The magic function `std::memcpy` is the tool of choice here:

```
__attribute__ ((noinline))
void SerializeTo(const vector<uint64_t>& v, uint8_t* dest) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
      std::memcpy(dest, std::addressof(v[i]), sizeof(v[i]));
    dest += sizeof(uint64_t);
  }
}
```

resulting output with `-std=c++11 -O3 -march=native  -Wall -pedantic`

```
SerializeTo(std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned char*):   # @SerializeTo(std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned char*)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        cmp     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rax
        je      .LBB0_3
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx]
        mov     qword ptr [rsi + 8*rcx], rax
        add     rcx, 1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        sub     rdx, rax
        sar     rdx, 3
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        jb      .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/g/ReGA9N

Comment: Thanks Richards. What about the following solution?

void SerializeTo(const vector<uint64_t>& v, uint8_t* dest) {
  union U {
    uint64_t val;
    uint8_t buf[sizeof(uint64_t)];
  };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    reinterpret_cast<U*>(dest)->val = v[i];
    dest += sizeof(uint64_t);
  }
}

Comment: @Roman it works in c++ only because the destination type is `uin8_t[]`. In general, type punning through a union is UB in C++, but there is a specific rule to allow it for uint8_t. In the general case, memcpy is better (and is no less efficient, because the compiler recognises it as magic).

Comment: @Roman re shorter code, do you mean assembler or source? For me on gcc7 it produces exactly the same object code.

Comment: try this one: clang goes crazy and creates two code paths - a super-efficient one for aligned addresses and large blocks plus code to handle the unaligned edge cases `__attribute__ ((noinline))
void SerializeTo(const vector<uint64_t>& v, uint8_t* dest) {
    for(auto&& x : v) {
      std::memcpy(dest, std::addressof(x), sizeof(x));
      dest += sizeof(x);
    }
}
`

Answer (score 2):

You stepped by 6 bytes into the array, so it's non-aligned now. The compiler can't know that it must avoid instructions requiring alignment; this is why type punning is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's unaligned. I think compiler should generate code that can handle unaligned address if it can not be sure that the address is aligned. Don't you agree?

Comment: The compiler "knows" that the address is aligned because all valid ways of making such a pointer produce aligned addresses.  (Here, "knows" means "can assume, because the alternative is undefined behavior where the result doesn't matter".)

Comment: @Roman: Even if the data was aligned, the compiler is under no obligation to produce valid code when you violate strict aliasing. (It's undefined behavior)

Comment: I disagree. Last time I checked I can write into arbitrary memory locations that belong to my process. Also SerializeTo is not inlined so it can not assume that `dest` is aligned. Imagine that memcpy will suddenly decide that it's arguments should be aligned. It's nonsense

Comment: @AndyG how come I violate strict aliasing? I thought it's valid to cast into uint8_t ?

Comment: @Roman: The kernel and processor will let you write to whatever memory location with an instruction valid for it.  But your beef is with the compiler (aka C++), not the OS.  C++ says you can't do this, and now you know why.  `memcpy` takes `void*`, so of course it doesn't know what alignment requirements there are.

Comment: @DavisHerring I do not understand what does it mean " C++ says you can't do this, and now you know why.". And replacing type of dest with "void*" does not solve it of course

Comment: Roman: If you'd like to know more, see the part in the standard (e.g. the N4296 draft you can find for free) under [basic.lval] that starts with "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
following types the behavior is undefined"

Comment: @Roman: C++ is not an assembler.  The compiler very helpfully uses high-performance instructions without you asking more than "`-O3` please".  The price of that is that you must play by the language's rules or bad things happen, as you have seen.  I didn't say "use `void*`"; I said that there's a reason that `memcpy` has looser requirements.

Comment: @AndyG thanks, you are right. I thought if one of the types is (unsigned) char then it's safe to cast both ways. Apparently only 1 direction is valid.